# How To Enable Syntax Highlighting for Nano In Windows?

Tags: command-line, text-editors, syntax-highlighting, nano

I am a huge fan of the nano editor, but I can't get the syntax highlighting to work in the windows version. Is it possible to have syntax highlighting in windows?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that nobody tell you that the native Windows API version of [Nano](https://github.com/lhmouse/nano-win), require you to use `POSIX` paths for the syntax highlighter files `*.nanorc` in your include statement in `.nanorc`.

Edit your `.nanorc` in `C:\Users\<username>\.nanorc` and make sure the import lines reads something like this:

```python
#include "C:\nano\nanorc\*.nanorc"     # Windows paths does NOT work!
include "/nano/nanorc/*.nanorc"        # This works!
```

Answer (score 0):

**The selected answer by James Baxter is incorrect.**

In order to enable syntax highlighting for `nano` in Cygwin, you will need to create `~/.nanorc`, which is the file that `nano` looks for when loading syntax highlighting.

In this file you should include whatever `include` statements containing paths to the syntax highlighting files, which are usually located in `/usr/share/nano`.

**The contents of my `~/.nanorc`:**

```
include /usr/share/nano/asm.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/autoconf.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/awk.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/c.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/changelog.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/cmake.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/css.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/debian.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/default.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/elisp.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/fortran.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/gentoo.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/go.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/groff.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/guile.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/html.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/java.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/javascript.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/json.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/lua.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/makefile.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/man.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/mgp.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/mutt.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/nftables.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/objc.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/ocaml.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/patch.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/perl.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/php.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/po.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/postgresql.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/pov.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/ruby.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/rust.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/spec.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/tcl.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/tex.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/texinfo.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/xml.nanorc
```

**The easiest way to do this is a simple one-liner:**

`ls -1 /usr/share/nano | sed 's@^@include /usr/share/nano/@' > ~/.nanorc`

*If your `/usr/share/nano` does not already contain any `.nanorc` files, just [download them from the Git repo](https://github.com/nanorc/nanorc).*

Comment: Your answer does not work natively in the _Windows version_ - please provide instructions without Cygwin or retract down vote!

Comment: I would retract the downvote, but my answer is literally locked in unless you edit your answer.  Your answer is misleading because you are directly referencing Cygwin, which led me to believe this is what the question was asking.  You are using Cygwin, but your answer is incorrect for nano under Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: Absolutely no point of adding the files one at the time. Use a wildcard.

Comment: This is not adding the files one at a time.  It is filtering the output of `ls` and adding the word "include" so that the lines are formatted correcly in the `.nanorc` file.